# main arguments change my default location

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

When I pass arguments to the `Main` function `static void Main(string[] args)`, the default location of my application changes to whatever `args[0]` contains.

For example, I have a file "test.txt" located in the same folder as the application exe. If I call `File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open);` there won't be any problems opening the file. Now, if I have passed arguments to `Main` calling `File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open);` will look for the file "test.txt" at the location of `args[0]`, not from the exe location.

Let's say my exe is located at `C:\users\application.exe` and the string of `args[0]` is `D:\files\music`, the line `File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open);` will try to open the file `D:\files\music\test.txt` instead of `C:\users\test.txt`.

How to fix this so that I can still have access to the file "test.txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using **relative paths**.
However, relative paths are relative to the current directory, not the location of your EXE file.

Instead, you can explicitly build an absolute path:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectory(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location), "test.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply SLaks, this solved my problem and I also got better understanding of how relative paths work.